# How to scroll block div in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, smooth-scrolling

I use [library](https://github.com/d-oliveros/ngSmoothScroll) `ngSmoothScroll`:

But this code scrolls pages, not block:

```
var element = document.getElementById('bottomDialog');
smoothScroll(element);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="list">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   ....
   <div id=bottomDialog"></div>
</div>
```

Also I tried:

```
// Inside ng-repeat
<div smooth-scroll scroll-if="{{ $last }}" duration="2500">{{...}}</div>
```

It scrolls page but not block

Comment: i think `<div id=bottomDialog" smooth-scroll></div>` would be enough

Comment: Does not work such. This works, but scrolls again page: `smooth-scroll scroll-if="{{ $last }}" duration="2500"`

Answer (score 0):

the libray you are using do not do what you want, it only scroll to the specify element.

Try using one of those bellow:

https://github.com/asafdav/ng-scrollbar

https://github.com/asafdav/ng-scrollbar